# How do I check which input button has been pressed in PHP?

Tags: php, html, post, textarea

so I'm new to php and I have two buttons on this html page here (the id value is included in the url):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<title>StoryBlox is a Social Story Builder Tool</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- these support the header/footer formatting -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/header_footer.css">
<script src="js/header.js"></script>
<?php //include_once 'confirm_login.php' 
    include_once 'story_manager.php';
    include_once 'open_connection.php';
    //include_once 'functions.php';
    //sec_session_start();
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $str_id = $_GET['id'];
        $draft_id = get_story_attribute($str_id, 'draft');
    }else{
        echo "Invalid story id.";
        echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper_main">
    <div id="wrapper_content">

        <?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

        <h1>Welcome to StoryBlox Create Story!</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- menu -->
    <!--<div id="inputs"> -->
    <form id="create_form" action="save_story.php?id=<?php echo $str_id?>" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="storyTitle" id="title" placeholder="Enter title." autofocus/><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="storyDesc" id="description" placeholder="Enter description here."></textarea>

        <div id="footer">
            <input type="button" name="draftBtn" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="Save as Draft"/>
            <input type="button" name="finalBtn" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="Finished!"/>
        </div>
    </form>

    </div>
</div>
<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>
```

When I click one of these two buttons, I'm brought to this php document here:

```
include_once 'open_connection.php';
include_once 'story_manager.php';
$mysqli = open_connection();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
if(isset($_POST['draftBtn'])){
    $title = $_POST['storyTitle'];
    $desc = $_POST['storyDesc'];
    $str_id = $_GET['id'];
    update_story_title($str_id, $title);
    //update_story_description($str_id, $desc);
    header('Location: createStory.php');
}
elseif(isset($_POST['finalBtn'])){
    $title = $_POST['storyTitle'];
    $desc = $_POST['storyDesc'];
    $str_id = $_POST['storyID'];
    update_story_title($str_id, $title);
    //update_story_description($str_id, $desc);
    save_draft_as_completed($str_id);
    header('Location: ../home.php');
}else{ echo "failed";}
}?>
```

And I always get "failed" printed out on my page. I've been Googling this for hours and I don't understand where I'm going wrong here. If anybody could help that would be appreciated. Also, if anyone could shed some light on what the equivalent to

```
<input type="textarea">
```

would be that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` produce? Also I know that having 2 submit buttons does work and will only send which one was clicked.

Comment: change the type of your input to 'submit' instead of 'button'

Comment: What do you mean with the "equivalent to textarea" ?

Comment: @Brovoker, I just want to know if there's a multiline input type that I could pass through $_POST like the text box.

Comment: And what's wrong with textarea itself?

Comment: I'm just not sure if it works on it's own like that. Everything else needed to be an input. Will the contents of textarea be put into $_POST?

Comment: Yes, for example <input type="textarea" name="description" /> will be put into $_POST['description']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 <input type="submit" name="draftBtn" value="Save as Draft"/>
```

instead of the button types with their onclick events.

Comment: I'm getting the "invalid story id." error when I do this, and I'm no longer redirected to the save_story page.
And I know for a fact that I have an entry in my database with the correct id.

Comment: Wait it works, I just wasn't realizing that it was returning to the original page because of my header().

Answer (score 0):

try to use submit tag instead of button.
and if you want to use button tag then you can pass value through hidden field. set value of hidden field on click event.